# Materialize css DataTable

Tags: angular, material-design, materialize

I am making a simple demo with Angular 2 using materialize css.
I want to know is it possible with materialize to design a proper datatable like i found here  http://danielnagy.me/md-data-table/
If yes then please suggest me or any link that can help me.

**Here is my simple code** :

```
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col l8">
  <div class="card z-depth-1">
     <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">{{tableTitle}}</span><br/><br/>
        <table class="centered bordered responsive-table">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th>#</th>
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <th>Age</th>
                 <th>Address</th>
                 <th>Designation</th>
                 <th>Department</th>
                 <th>Salary</th>                   
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let item of empData;let i=index">
                 <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                 <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                 <td>{{item.Age}}</td>
                 <td>{{item.Address}}</td>
                 <td>{{item.Designation}}</td>
                 <td>{{item.Department}}</td>
                 <td>{{item.Salary}}</td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed with Tera Data covalent. You can check it here.
https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/data-table

I have checked this, This is really easy and just need to follow few steps to integrate.

Comment: I have checked this and its really nice but i am not finding proper installation guide

Comment: Is there any better installation guide i am finding it difficult on site pls suggest

Comment: Use "Data Table with components" it has search facility and sorting facility.you  just need to do is copy and past html and typescript codes to your component's typescript and html file. Then after you have to fill Tha data array with your own data objects.